# build_native.sh usage and make errors

Tags: android, android-ndk

very new to android development and shell scripts etc so please bear with me.

I executed build_native.sh and ran into the following errors:

1. `usage: dirname path`
   which seems to be coming from ndk-build -C
2. `make: *** No rule to make target`/Users/[username]/build/core/build-local.mk'.  Stop`.
   I've done my best to define all the paths etc
   but I've never defined anything for`/Users/[username]/build/core/build-local.mk` so I've no idea where that's coming from. and besides, that directory doesn't even exist!

p.s. i'm working under osx

can someone please help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

build-local.mk does exist under NDKDirectory/build/core. Probably you defined your NDK directory wrong or your NDK installation is incomplete.

Comment: thank you. yes indeed. build-local.mk does exist there. but the path i defined is: export NDK_ROOT='/Users/[username]/[more directories]/android_ndk'. not where its looking for this file...

Comment: Are you using ' or " when defining the path? This page suggests the second one. http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/android/9781849691529/setting-up-your-environment/ch01lvl1sec18

Comment: thanks, but sadly that's not making a difference in this case :S

Comment: Do you have spaces in your path? Or better, could you post the exact path of the NDK root?

Comment: there is yes. I could try getting rid of the spaces and replacing them with an underscore I guess. here's the exact path "~/Desktop/Android Development/android-sdk-macosx/android_ndk

Comment: that made the difference! thank you! at least now I'm getting more meaningful errors and I can work to solve them one by one. (such as: Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-17 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 10 in ./AndroidManifest.xml; Android NDK: You NDK_MODULE_PATH variable contains spaces, Please fix the error and start again.; ....setup-imports.mk:27: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.)

Comment: Glad that it worked. Never use spaces in any kind of development environment. That warning tells you about the platform mismatch in your make files and program's android app level defined in AndroidManifest.xml. Easy to fix, just make them the same.

Comment: been away for a couple days. I'm going to attempt the fix now, thank you.